# Return type declaration - Fatal error: must be instance of integer, integer returned return

Tags: php, return-type, php-7

I wanted to try out PHP 7's *return type declarations* (I am using PHP 7RC3 on windows for this purpose).

wanted to start with something very simple:

```
function getme() : integer
{
    return 434;
}
echo getme();
```

but this gives me an fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of getme() must be an instance of integer, integer returned

then i also tried to cast the return value, but
`return (integer) 434;` or `return (int) 434;` gives me the same error;

finally i also tried:

```
function getme() : integer
{
    $i = 434;
    return (integer) $i;
}
echo getme();
```

with the same result.

what am I doing wrong?
or what have I misunderstood here?

thanks for any explanations and help!

**UPDATE**
this is why I thought I had to use `integer` instead of `int` (special note to Toby Allen):

from https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types:

> Examples of Invalid Use
>   (...)

```
// Int is not a valid type declaration

function answer(): int {
    return 42;
}
answer();
```

Comment: It's looking for a class named `integer`, not a number.

Comment: @melpomene thanks, that's what i somehow thought too, because it expects an `instance of integer`

Comment: Surely there must be this basic level of documentation on the php 7 documentation website?

Comment: @TobyAllen then see my update

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> No new reserved words are added. The names int, float, string and
>   bool are recognised and allowed as type declarations, and prohibited
>   from use as class/interface/trait names (including with use and
>   class_alias).

From: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5

**TL/DR:**

```
function getme() : int
{
    return 434;
}

echo getme();
```

Comment: thank you! I just found out that using `int` as a return type works. seems like I misunderstood something about `integer` in the docs. will accept your answer as soon as I am able to.

Comment: would be nice if you could add a link to the source of your citation! thank you.